# How to change text to lower case for large number of files using command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a few html files. The links on these files are mixed of upper case and lower case whereas the name of the file are all in lowercase.

I want to make the text inside **href=".."** lowercase whatever case they are now. Can anyone help me with this?

The number of file is over 4000. I would to love to do it from command line. I have used fart to replace text. FART is quite good for that. Is it possible to use any preg_match to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So it is a one off thing for a lot of files.

I would use Notepad++ (free) or another text editor that allows find and replace using regular expressions.

1. From the Menu, click Search --> Replace --> Find in Files.
2. Make sure you check the "Regular expression" option.
3. Add a filter if you can to speed things up (ie. *.html).
4. In the "Find what:" box type `(href=['"])(.+)(['"])`.
5. In the "Replace with:" box type `\1\L\2\3`.

This will find all href="[link-text]" or href='[link-text]' and replace it with itself but the [link-text] in lowercase.